# Beautifulsoup print same class name different occurrences

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

My output is this as follows:

```
for foo in soup.findAll('li', class_= ['cell036 tal arrow','cell009']):
    bar = foo.find(['a'])
    #print(type(bar))
    if bar is None:
        print foo 
    else:
        print bar.text
```

It prints like

```
ALGYO
<li class="cell009">12,45</li>
<li class="cell009">54,65</li>...
```

...
...

I want only 1st occurrence and 5th occurrence of cell009 class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about methods of beautifulsoup, but a simple modification in above code can do your job:

```
i = 0
for foo in soup.findAll('li', class_= ['cell036 tal arrow','cell009']):
    bar = foo.find(['a'])
    #print(type(bar))
    if bar is None:
        print foo 
    elif i == 0 or i == 4:
        print bar.text
    i+=1
```

Comment: i tried these but foo is like a paragraph that cant loop like that also foo[1] not pulling what i need

Comment: Can you please post the content/link of the page you're trying to parse?